# List Contacts API with $search param against shared contact folder returns 403 but returns contacts if no $search

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We're listing contacts in a shared folder using `/users/id/contacts?$search="foo"` which returns a 403 on each call.  However, if we drop the `$search` query parameter the API returns contacts from the shared folder. We are using delegated permissions, and the requested scope is `Contacts.ReadWrite.Shared`.  Is there some other scope we need in order to be allowed to *search* the shared folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [MS Document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#search-parameter), we can currently search only message and person collections(such as [email](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#using-search-on-message-collections)(me/messages),[people](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#using-search-on-person-collections)(me/people),  [displayName and description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#using-search-on-directory-object-collections).etc).

So we couldn't use the search parameter here.

Alternatively,We can use the [`$filter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter) query parameter to search the users  contacts.

Comment: I read that, but aren't contacts a `person` collection?  You can use the `$search` parameter beautifully on your own contacts (e.g.,`/me/contacts?$search="foo"`)

Comment: Hi @GlennScott, You can use `$Search` on `contacts` using email properties. For example `me/messages?$search="kind:contacts"`.I hope this helps.

Comment: You can use $search on personal collections such as email(me/messages),people(me/people), displayName and description.etc.please go through the document I have shared in the answer for more reference.

Comment: Hari -- thank you, I've read that document twice, I will *definitely* go through it again. Be right back. Again, thank you for your patience.